# Inner Join problems PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables: bound, station and time

Bound has 2 columns: boundID and boundName

Station has 3 columns: stationID stationName boundID

Time has 4 columns: timeID departureTime tramID stationID

I am wanting to display the startStation and endStation the user enters into the form and display the time if the stations entered by the user in the textfields have the same boundID. Currently, this is all I have managed to do and can't seem to get a result. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    //display tram times from one station to another        
    ELSE if($startStation != '' && $endStation !='' && $DepartureTime =='' && $DepartureTime2 =='')
    $query ="SELECT b.boundName, s.stationName, t.departureTime
    FROM Station s, Time t, Bound b
    INNER JOIN Bound b
    ON S.boundID=B.boundID
    WHERE s.stationName = '$startStation'AND'$endStation'";
```

I get this message when I try this: "Not unique table/alias: 'b'"

This is an example of the data I have:

stationID       stationName   boundID

5       |        CitySquare    |  2 ________________________________________________________________________________ 
boundID   boundName

2  |     South-Southbound ________________________________________________________________________________

timeID  departureTime   tramID  stationID

1      |    07:18:00  |    1        |    5

The expected result is the user is able to insert a startStartion and an endStation and obtain the departure time, if the boundID are the same.

This is the result I want to output

Bound Name       |       Start Station      |    End Station       |    Departure Time

South-SouthBound     |       Stourton         |     CitySquare             |  09:49:00

Comment: please provide expected result set and data sample would be very helpful

Comment: Here is a screenshot displaying the database, variables and queries I am using.

Comment: no. in your screenshot almost nothing usefull. provide few line for avery table in your OP , and those records should be related to each other. for example take just one record from your `bound` table with id=2 and all related data from other tables

Comment: The boundID in the database is all related. However, the user cannot enter a boundID. They can simply search fro a startStation and an endStation. I want the startStation and endStation to display the times, if they have the same boundID

Comment: you don't listen. don't tell the story. provide data

Comment: stationID stationName boundID
 5 CitySquare 2                           ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ boundID boundName
 2 South-Southbound   ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ timeID departureTime    tramID   stationID
  1            07:18:00       1        5 _______________________________________________________________________________________ Would this suffice?

Comment: put it into your original post and provide expected result for this data set

Comment: there is no `INSERT` part in your code. so your expected result absolutely unclear. When I requested expected result I meant you should provide a record you want to get from mysql but not continue to tell your story. try to be more precise and technical instead of writing a story or fairy tail... :-( sorry, but the way you are asking just confuse me

Comment: @Alex Sorry, I think I understand what you mean. I have edited the original post and at the bottom is the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below portion of code

```
INNER JOIN Bound b
```

with

```
INNER JOIN Bound c
```

and change the alias names of the columns too. There are too same alias assignment found in your query

It will make confusion while compile the query. Mysql cound not understand which table you are referring to.

**Edit:**

Try with the below code. I am not sure which table have the "boundID" field

```
 $query ="SELECT b.boundName, s.stationName, t.departureTime
FROM Station s, Time t, Bound b
INNER JOIN Bound c
ON s.boundID=b.boundID
WHERE s.stationName = '$startStation'AND'$endStation'";
```

Comment: Like this? Now I am getting a 'Unknown column 'S.boundID' in 'on clause'' message.                                                                                                      //display tram times from one station to another  
  ELSE if($startStation != '' && $endStation !='' && $DepartureTime =='' && $DepartureTime2 =='')
  $query ="SELECT b.boundName, s.stationName, t.departureTime
  FROM Station s, Time t, Bound b
  INNER JOIN Bound c
  ON S.boundID=B.boundID
  WHERE s.stationName = '$startStation'AND'$endStation'";  @Arun

Comment: the alias name is case sensitive. If you use "S" then through out you have to use the same

Comment: now I am receiving the error "Not unique table/alias: 'b'" again :/

Comment: Show the rendered query with actual values other than variables

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img924/5562/Yc5mXL.png here is a screenshot displaying everything; database tables, queries and variables

Comment: @Farhad95, There is nothing to do with individual data. You just run  the big query and see what is happening

Comment: I have ran the query and I get the error 'Not unique table/alias: 'b''.

Comment: There is no chance of that error. Check if you are giving 'b' in two places

Comment: I appreciate your help. I have managed to get rid of that error however, I receive the message 'Unknown column 's.boundID' in 'on clause'' now. I have a boundID column in Bound set as a primary key, and a boundID in Station set as a foreign key within my database as shown in the screenshot link I posted in the previous comments. Here is what I have so far:

Comment: ELSE if($startStation != '' && $endStation !='' && $DepartureTime =='' && $DepartureTime2 ==''){
  $query ="SELECT b.boundName as bound_name, s.stationName as station_name, t.departureTime as departure_time
  FROM Station as s, Time as t, Bound as b
  INNER JOIN Bound as c
  ON s.boundID = c.boundID
  WHERE s.stationName = '$startStation' 
  AND s.stationName = '$endStation'
  AND s.boundID = b.boundID";
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query to something like below:

```
SELECT b.boundName as bond_name, s.stationName as station_name, t.departureTime as departure_time
FROM Station as s, Time as t, Bound as b
INNER JOIN Bound as b
ON s.boundID = b.boundID
WHERE s.stationName = '$startStation' AND s.stationName = '$endStation'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DB schema is a bit weird to me. From my point of view you are missing a lot of necessary data columns in your tables.

But just to get your expected result you can try this query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5ef0/1

```
SELECT 
   b.boundName `Bound Name`,
   s.stationName  `Start Station`,
   e.stationName `End Station`,
   t.departureTime `Departure Time`
FROM station s
INNER JOIN station e
ON e.boundId = s.boundId
  AND e.stationName='$endStation'
INNER JOIN bound b
ON b.boundId=s.boundId
INNER JOIN `time` t
ON t.stationId=s.stationId
WHERE s.stationName = '$startStation'
```